# GCP - Insert a record into bigquery table from cloud function using Python

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

My requirement is to insert a record into big-query table from cloud function

Cloud function is trigger from other application and insert the requested json to big query table.

```
import logging
import sys

def saveResponse(data):
    # Construct a BigQuery client object.
    ## Get Biq Query Set up
    client = bigquery.Client()
    table_id = "<table_id>"
    table = client.get_table(table_id)

    rows_to_insert = [data]

    # Make an API request.
    errors = client.insert_rows(table, rows_to_insert) 
    if errors == []:
        print("Record created")
    else:
        print("Encountered errors while inserting rows: {}".format(errors))


@functions_framework.http
def create_http(request):

    # Set CORS headers for the preflight request
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        # Allows GET requests from any origin with the Content-Type
        # header and caches preflight response for an 3600s
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, access-control-allow-origin, Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
        }
        return ('', 204, headers)

    # Set CORS headers for the main request
    headers = {
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    }

    if request.method == 'POST':
        content_type = request.headers['Content-Type']
        if content_type == 'application/json':
            request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
            _sdata = saveResponse(request_json)
            # logger.info(_sdata);
            return (request_json, 200, headers)
            # return request_json;
```

Not able to insert a record in bigquery

Comment: What is not working? Is there an error message or stack trace?

Comment: Yes, I got some logs and was able to resolve the issue @JohnHanley
Thank you.